# access HttpContext.Current from WCF Web Service

Tags: wcf, service, httpcontext

I just started using WCF Services with ASP.NET AJAX.  I instantiate my WCF service from Javascript and then pass string variables as arguments to my WCF Service method (with an OperationContract signature).  I then return a .NET object (defined with a DataContract) which is bound to my custom Javascript class.  I'm having trouble authenticating based on the user logged into my web session.  However, the WCF web service is a completely different service with no context to the HttpContext.Current object.  What is the most secure way to get access to that object?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can get access to `HttpContext.Current` by enabling AspNetCompatibility, preferably via configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

That in turn allows you to get access to the current user: `HttpContext.Current.User` - which is what you're after, right?

You can even enforce AspNetCompatibility by decorating your service class with an additional attribute:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

(In the `System.ServiceModel.Activation` namespace.)
If that attribute is in place, your service will fail to start unless AspNetCompatibility is enabled!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I gave you a point.  I'll mark my answer once I have test this out.  We are storing the user slightly differently in our application, so we'll have to redesign things as they recommend for forms authentication.  Then I can use this approach.

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works if your service is hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 27):

You do not have a HttpContext by default but you have many of the same objects present in the OperationContext (which is always present) or the WebOperationContext (which is only available for certain bindings.

You can access the OperationContext or WebOperationContext by using the static `.Current` property like so:  `WebOperationContext.Current`

Comment: +1 this should be the accepted answer. We are dealing with WCF which could be hosted in a Windows Service or self-hosted. AspNetCompatilibity is just an old habit.

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want to change Web.config or you cannot change it:

```
private string GetClientIPAddress()
        {
            var props = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
            var endpointProperty = props[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
            if (endpointProperty != null)
            {
                if (endpointProperty.Address == "::1" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointProperty.Address))
                    return "127.0.0.1";

                return endpointProperty.Address;
            }

            return String.Empty;
        }
```