# HttpSelfHostServer and HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext, self-hosting

I'm working on a self-hosted ASP.NET web api-application.
Everything works fine, but now I'm struggling with `HttpContext`:

I need to save session-informations from the client.
But `HttpContext.Current` is always null.
So it's obvious that my `HttpSelfHostServer` don't work with the static HttpContext-Class.

The thing I don't understand is: why..?
And I can't figure out a way to tell neither `HtttpSelfHostServer` nor `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` to work with `HttpContext`.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Creating a `HttpSelfHostConfiguration`

   - 1.1 Adding `Service-Resolvers` & `Routes`
   - 1.2 Adding custom `UserNamePassword-Validator`
2. create new Instance of HttpSelfHostServer with the config

   - 2.1 `server.OpenAsync().Wait()`

Any help how I can tell my server to work with `HttpContext.Current` is greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: Maybe need `AspNetCompatibility`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904313/access-httpcontext-current-from-wcf-web-service

Comment: hi mellamokb. Thanks, but if I use the aspNetCompatibelity-Mode, I'm still going to neeed a IIS, which is the thing I want to avoid.

Comment: Also note the second answer in the link I posted refers to a lot of the same information being available in OperationContext.  What exactly do you need out of the HttpContext?

Comment: OperationContext only exists in the WCF world, not in ASP.Net WebApi

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You won't be able to use HttpContext in a self-hosted environment. HttpContext is set by the ASP.Net pipeline, which you won't have if you don't run under IIS/ASP.Net.

The HttpContext is only available in the Web-Hosting mode, in which the HttpControllerHandler creates the request.

FYI- I invite you to read the following great articles from Pedro Felix to better understand the different hosting models:

- [HTTP processing architecture overview](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/asp-net-web-api-processing-architecture/)
- [Web-hosting](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/asp-net-web-api-web-hosting/)
- [Self-hosting](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/asp-net-web-api-self-hosting/)

Answer (score 13):

To get around this problem (I find I am using a lot of components these days that need to work equally well in Web API and MVC), you can try this old shim I wrote to give you back an HttpContext-like interface that works in both flavours. It's on NuGet also, here's the source: 
[Link on github](https://github.com/danielcrenna/graveyard/tree/master/httpcontext-shim)
(or [Link on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpContextShim))

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this here and to Github; I had a legacy component that expects to float around in a static variable on the current thread, and this shim beats it into submission even under SelfHost. Works like a charm!

Comment: What you are offering seems very cool. However, I was unable to see whether it supports replacements of the `HttpSession` object - `HttpContext.Current.Session` seems unavailable. Does your library support session state? If not, could you recommend any way to get a session state replacement? Could I use `HttpContext.Current.Items` ?

Comment: this somehow removed my system.web.http 5.2.3.0 reference and replaced it with 4.0.0.0, got loads of build errors from it

Comment: @DaniëlTulp too late to be valuable but for the next person I'd just pull the code from https://github.com/danielcrenna/vault

Comment: @DanielCrenna which of those projects in particular Daniel?