# Windows authentication and Asp.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have an Intranet application with Windows authentication based on MVC4.

When I need the WindowsIdentity for authorization purpose in a Controller I just use

```
 HttpContext.User.Identity
```

Now I wanted to use the new Asp.Net WebAPI for some Ajax calls.

Is there a way to get the WindowsIdenty object in the same easy way as in an MVC Controller?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please don't reference the `HttpContext` from a controller.

You can access the Controllers [`User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property which is way of accessing the Identity through without a dirrect reference to `HttpContext`.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
         var indenty = this.User.Identity;
    }
}
```

**Why**

The controllers `User` property provides a level of abstraction which allows for easier mocking and thus unit testing. This abstraction also allows for greater portability e.g. if this was WebApi Self Host you wouldn't even have access to `HttpContext`.

To read more about how to unit test and mock the User property read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006624/how-to-mock-httpcontext-user-identity-name-in-asp-net-mvc-4). For more information re: portability read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347807/httpselfhostserver-and-httpcontext-current).

Comment: One small clarification: If you want the Identity use User.Identity

Comment: Well I appreciate the clarity of the answer, it would be for everyone's edification if you explained WHY one wouldn't reference HttpContext from a controller.

Comment: @dansan thanks for the comment. I have put a brief explanation as to why.