# How to Mock HttpContext.User.Identity.Name in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have code in the controller which consumes `HttpContext`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   var currentUser=HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
   ......

}
```

While trying to write test using NUnit like this

```
[Test]
public void CanDisplayRequest()
{
    //Act
    var result=  (ViewResult)_requestController.Index();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<OrderRequest>(resut.Model);
}
```

Test will fail because it couldn't find `HttpContext`

So how can I mock `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

I'm using Moq for Mocking

Answer (score 60, accepted):

you can initialize your controller with fake context with fake principal  as shown below

```
var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("User");
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(principal);
var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);

_requestController = new RequestController();

//Set your controller ControllerContext with fake context
_requestController.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
```

Comment: Do guys also have a snippet for doing the same thing but uses microsft fakes/test and not any other 3rd party testing framework?

Answer (score 5):

To do it using Microsoft tests only (no 3rd party frameworks), you can do as below:

```
public class MockHttpContextBase : HttpContextBase
{
    public override IPrincipal User { get; set; }

}
```

And then...

```
        var userToTest = "User";
        string[] roles = null;

        var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity(userToTest);
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, roles);
        var fakeHttpContext = new MockHttpContextBase { User = principal };
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext
        {
            HttpContext = fakeHttpContext
        };

        // This is the controller that we wish to test:
        _requestController = new RequestController();

        // Now set the controller ControllerContext with fake context
        _requestController.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

Comment: This solution is working for me in the ASP.Net MVC application when creating a Test Case.