# How to register IAuthenticationManager via Unity in Web API 2 Self-Hosted app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin, self-hosting

I want my Web API app to sign in users via ASP.NET Identity.
In my `AuthController` I do the following:

`//...getting claimsIdentity etc...`

`_authenticationManager.SignIn(claimsIdentity)`

where `_authenticationManager` is an instance of `IAuthenticationManager`

I'm using Unity so `IAuthenticationManager` is registered in the following way:

`container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));`

And that works for my app that is hosted in IIS. But I also have some integration tests that are run on the self-hosted environment and the problem is that `IAuthenticationManager` resolution fails because `HttpContext.Current` is null.

Is there any way to register `IAuthenticationManager` implementation and use it in both self-hosted and IIS? I do also want to be able to inject this dependency via my controller's constructor in unit tests.

Comment: depends on code of your clinet class where you are using IAuthenticationManager. Most likely case when you send you dependencies as IAManager to constructor of some class. So that you can inject you mock to constructor.

Comment: Yep, I'm using constructor injection to push IAManager to my controller. The question is how to resolve the real (not the mocked) implementation, provided by ASP.NET Identity in the self-hosted environment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347807/httpselfhostserver-and-httpcontext-current
so you have to use different container setup for self-hosting app

Comment: But how can I get the IAManager instance in a different way, not from HttpContext.Current or HttpRequestMessage (which is only available in the controller instance)?

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding below line in unity.config :

```
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
```