# Calling "new [classname]" is giving nullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net

I made a new class, and I'm getting a null reference exception, and I cannot figure out why.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    namespace TIMBaseClasses.ReturnerTracking
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Returner
    {
            private Guid _returnerID;
            private string _clientIP;

            public Guid returnerID {get { return _returnerID; } set { _returnerID = value; }}
            public string clientIP {get { return _clientIP; } set { _clientIP = value; }}


            /// <summary>Constructor that sets the default values as needed</summary>
            public Returner()
            {
                returnerID = Guid.Empty;
                clientIP = string.Empty;
            }

            public static Returner Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    var ret = (Returner)(HttpContext.Current.Session["Returner"] ?? new Returner());
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Returner"] = ret;
                    return ret;
                }
            }


    }
}
```

The error happens towards the bottom, on the "var ret" line at the end when I call "new Returner()".

The line that calls it that causes the error is as follows.

```
 Returner.Instance.returnerID = id;
```

EDIT

To address the concerns that the HTTPContext.Current is null, I did a watch and it is not null. However, a watch on "new Returner()" gives me this:

```
Instance = 'TIMBaseClasses.ReturnerTracking.Returner.Instance' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

Comment: It's possible that `HttpContext.Current` is null if you're calling this from the wrong thread or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its probably more likely that HTTPContext.Current or HTTPContext.Current.Session is null

Comment: A watch on the line confirms that it is not null. The Session is null, and the null coalescence operator then shuffles us over to "new Returner()" which is null somehow.

Comment: The entire session is null? Or just the value returned by Session["ret"] ?

Comment: Nevermind. I cleaned and rebuilt and now the error is pointing to the HTTPContext.Current being null, just as you said. Thanks.

Comment: If you know of a way to get around that being null when calling from a webservice that would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904313/access-httpcontext-current-from-wcf-web-service

Answer (score 5):

Is `HTTPContext.Current` non-null? If it is `null`, you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: A watch confirms that it is not null.

Answer (score 1):

your property `HTTPContext.Current`  is null